server hardware dataset for training SpaCy text annotator
I was looking for a server hardware dataset to train my NER model specifically my SpaCy annotator to detect different components from unstructured data and give me properties associated with the component

First option was to manually do it from an open source NER annotator( https://tecoholic.github.io/ner-annotator/)
Train it on existing data
create my own dataset

if i were to choose any of these routes an advice or suggestions ?or is there any other way i am not looking into
https://tecoholic.github.io/ner-annotator/
